# How to use the favicon_maker gem by Follmann

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm still a bit new to the world of Rails and was wondering if it would be possible to get a bit of help with using the favicon_maker gem by follmann.

https://github.com/follmann/favicon_maker

The existing readme is not terribly verbose and difficult to get running. If anyone has any tips or advice that would be amazing.

Detailed description of what I have tried in a GIT issue here:

https://github.com/follmann/favicon_maker/issues/23

Comment: The issue says no such file or directory `convert`. Just run `which convert` in you terminal and post the output.

Comment: If it doesn't output any directory then you need to install [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php).

Comment: output of which convert:

```
convert not found
```

Installing via homebrew now and will let you know how it goes.